# what is possible reason cause the date not format in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, date-formatting

I don't understand why this happen, the below code is work fine in one project and is able to show "09-06-2013" but not working in another project, date displayed was "09/06/2013 00:00:00".???? Why???

Model:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}")]
public DateTime dtBegin
{
    get {
        if (mdtBegin.Year  == 1)
        {
            return DateTime.Now;
        }
        else
        {
            return mdtBegin;
        }
    }
    set { mdtBegin = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the .DisplayFor() or the .EditorFor() helpers?

The DisplayFormat attribute won't work with helpers such as .TextBoxFor().

Comment: Still the same..for .EditFor() and .DisplayFor(). i tried in different View it's work in the same project.